# Call a method on string by on creation of a new string object

Tags: ruby

Ok, so I have a method colourize dynamically patched in string class:

```
class String
    @@colours = [[154, 184, 208, 203, 198, 164, 129, 92], [63, 33, 39, 44, 49, 83, 118], [40,41,42,43,211, 210, 209, 208]].tap { |itself| itself.concat(itself.map(&:reverse)) }

    define_method(:colourize) do |final = ''|
        colour = @@colours.sample
        colour_size = colour.size - 1
        index, div, val = 0, length / colour_size, ''
        div = 1 if div == 0
        colour_size -= 1

        each_char.with_index do |c, i|
            index += 1 if (i % div == 0 && index < colour_size) && i > 1
            val.concat("\e[38;5;#{colour[index]}m#{c}")
        end

        val + "\e[0m" + final
    end
end
```

This colourizes a String object (tested only in a BASH shell on a Linux system). But I have to write the colourize method every time.

`puts 'Hello World'.colourize`

Is there a way to patch String so that when a 'Hello World' is created or assigned to a variable, it will, by default, call the colourize method?

Patching String#intialize doesn't simply work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without patching the ruby source. The string initializer is not called when ruby creates a string.

Comment: `String` holds and modifies characters. Colorizing is more related to output. Have you considered patching `puts` instead or adding your own `puts` method?

Comment: Ok so my question is quite dumb  ... We can define a puts method just like this:
`define_method(:puts) do |*arg| ; Kernel.puts(arg.map { |x| x.kind_of?(String) ? x.colourize : x }) ; end ; puts "Hello world", 5, [1,2,3,4]` ... I have tried to patch to_s method in class String first, doesn't work  because when we create a string, we don't call String#initialize all the time, and when we puts some string, we don't call to_s method but when we p some string, we call the inspect method!

Comment: @S.Goswami setting `$stdout` to an object that implements a custom `puts` might be cleaner that patching `Kernel`. You could write a simple decorator using [`SimpleDelegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define a class `MyString` (not a subclass of `String`)? For example, `ms = MyString.new("Hello, World")` and `ms.str` would return a colourized version of `"Hello, World"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to patch String so […] it will, by default, call the colourize method?

This is a bad idea. Strings are fundamental to Ruby, just like arrays, hashes and symbols. Putting color codes in every created string, no matter what, will most likely break something.

You should only add the color codes when actually printing the string (and probably only when you're printing to a tty).

This brings us to `puts`. It writes the given objects to standard out, converting them to strings if needed. Unfortunately, a string doesn't need any conversion, so the call to `to_s` is skipped and we have no method to hook into.

But instead of patching `String`, we could patch the top-level `puts`:

(I'm using `upcase` for demonstration purposes because I can't render ANSI escape sequences here)

```
def puts(*args)
  Kernel.puts(*args.map { |a| a.is_a?(String) ? a.upcase : a })
end

puts 'hello'
```

Output:

```
HELLO
```

Since patching core classes is a dirty business, let's see if we can find a cleaner approach. The documentation for [`Kernel.puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) says:

> Equivalent to `$stdout.puts(obj, ...)`

That sounds promising: `$stdout` being a global variable can be changed easily. All we need is an object that provides a custom `puts` method and delegates any other method to the original stdout. This is what [`SimpleDelegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) is for:

```
class OutputDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def puts(*args)
    super *args.map { |a| a.is_a?(String) ? a.upcase : a }
  end
end
```

Let's give it a try:

```
puts 'before'

$stdout = OutputDecorator.new($stdout)

puts 'within'

$stdout = $stdout.__getobj__

puts 'after'
```

Output:

```
before
WITHIN
after
```

Comment: That's a very clean approach. Thank you very much. Also, `$stdout.puts('within')` or `Kernel.puts('within')` will be upcased, but `STDOUT.puts('within')` will not. That's nice because if you can still use `STDOUT.puts()` before assigning `$stdout` with `__getobject__ `.